# Check Zagier theorem about Mahler's measure

Tags: plotting, polynomials, number-theory

I want to check the following theorem  by using *Mathematica*:

(from [Heights of Polynomials and Entropy in Algebraic Dynamics, page 22](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=qs_TBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA22))

> $\textbf{Theorem}.$ Let $\omega$ denote a primitive $6th$ root of unity. Suppose $F\in \mathbb{Z}(x)$ has degree $d$, and $F(0)F(1)F(\omega)\neq0.$ then $$m(F)+m(F_{*})\geq \frac{d}{2}\log\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)$$
>   with equality if and only if  $F$ or $F_{*}$ is a power of $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1.$

Where $$M(F)=|a_d|\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{d} \max\lbrace1,|\alpha_i|\rbrace$$
is a [Mahler's measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_measure), for any non-zero polynomial

$$F(x)=a_dx^d+a_{d-1}x^{d-1}...+a_0.$$

$F_{*}(x)=F(1-x)$ and logarithmic Mahler's measure $m(F)=\log M(F)$

I tried:

first I define logarithmic  Mahler's measure $m(F)$

```
m[p_, x_] := Log[Module[{roots = x /. {ToRules[NRoots[p == 0, x]]}},
Abs[Function[x, p][0]] Times @@ (Max[Abs[#], 1] & /@ roots)]];
```

then define random polynomial $F(x)$

```
Frandompol[x_, n_, r_List] :=Nest[# x + Random[Integer, r] &, 0, n + 1]
```

I want to do something like this

```
DiscretePlot[{m[f[x], x] + m[f[1 - x], x], 
d/2 Log[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2]}, {n, 1, 1000}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

and show that red points are greater than green points.

```
DiscretePlot[{(m[Frandompol[x, n, {-1, 1}], x] + m[Frandompol[(1 - x), n,{-1, 1}], x]), 
Exponent[Frandompol[x, n, {-1, 1}], x]/2 Log[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2]}, 
{n,2, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

I checked equality for $F=(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)^n$

```
f[x_, n_] := (x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)^n

N[Table[(m[f[x, n], x] + m[f[(1 - x), n], x]), {n, 1, 500}], 15] === 
N[Table[ Exponent[f[x, n], x]/2 Log[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2], {n, 1, 500}],15]

True
```

and it holds for $n=1$ to $500$

Comment: You can use `RootSum[]` for the logarithmic Mahler measure: `m[p_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[p, x] := RootSum[Function[x, p], Log[Max[Abs[#], 1]] &] + Log[Abs[Coefficient[p, x, Exponent[p, x]]]]`. Note that you're supposed to use the leading coefficient, not the constant term.

Comment: Since you specify `n` in `Frandompol`, then you know the degree of your polynomial, no? In any case, you can use `Exponent[]`.

Comment: @J.M. ok. But something is wrong here  `DiscretePlot[{(m[Frandompol[x, n, {-1, 1}], x] + 
    m[1 - Frandompol[x, n, {-1, 1}], x]), 
  Exponent[Frandompol[x, n, {-1, 1}], x]/2 Log[(1 + Sqrt[5])/2]}, {n, 
  2, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]` red points are not greater than green. see [here](http://i.imgur.com/5vfGTDP.png)

Comment: Before anything else: I'm aware of what a Mahler measure is, but I cannot seem to find your quoted theorem among Zagier's work. Can you please edit your question to include a reference to this theorem?

Comment: @J.M. I edit my question, there was a my mistake, $F_{*}=F(1-x)$ instead  $F_{*}=1-F(x)$. but result is same

Comment: As I noted, you should also check your definition of the Mahler measure, since you are using the constant term instead of the leading coefficient. Did you also verify that your random polynomials are not zero at $0$, $1$, or $\exp(\pm \pi i/3)$? Lastly, `GoldenRatio` is built-in.